# Can I still ssh into my server if I forward port 22?

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

If I set up "forwarding" with [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) as

```
myserver:~$ sshuttle -r username@TARGET 0.0.0.0/0
```

Will I be still able to ssh into `myserver` from `mymachine`? I guess not, but I am afraid to try.

---

Alternatively if I forward just port `22`

```
myserver:~$ ssh -nNT -L 0.0.0.0:22:localhost:22 TARGET
```

Is there a way to ssh into `myserver`? Or in case you want to do that, you need to open extra port for ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh someserver -R 10022:127.0.0.1:22 -fN` will allow you to ssh to your machine directly on port 22, and on `someserver` on port 10022, which will direct you to your server on port 22.

That is so because the daemon keeps listening on the port it's configured to listen to, and because it can maintenance more than one simultaneous ssh sessions (of course assuming that you haven't limited that in your `sshd_config`).

Answer (score 0):

*On a second look it seems you are trying to use these tools designed for a client from your server "`myserver`". My answer covers the situation where you are using them on the client, "`mymachine`".*

The documentation for this `sshuttle` project seems rather unorthodox: even the [How it works](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/blob/master/docs/how-it-works.rst) article tells only *what it does*. It compares the project to other tools mainly by telling how it doesn't work: it's not "like" a SSH port forward but it's not "like" a ["stupid/complex VPN"](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/blob/master/docs/overview.rst) either. Apparently the author seems to think he has invented something all new and of course better than anyone else has before.

What we can tell based on short read through of the documentation ([requirements](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/blob/master/docs/requirements.rst), [usage](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle/blob/master/docs/usage.rst)) is that it

- can *proxy* all traffic to the other side, using `iptables` (NAT) or `recmsg` (TPROXY)
- doesn't need admin access on the remote server, but root access on the client machine
- utilizes Python on both ends.

Based on that, also SSH to the remote side might get proxied, but **that shouldn't matter**, because you can probably **`ssh` from the remote server to itself** using the external IP address; it doesn't make any difference from which side of the tunnel the connection originates.

I don't know what you are trying to do with your alternative solution as it's not even trying to achieve the same results than the first one. However, you can't bind to local port `22` unless you are root and there isn't `sshd` already listening. Even if you succeed, I can't see how this adds anything useful. But, to answer the question: yes, you can still `ssh` to `remote:22` (+ the local port forwarded).

Comment: Ad sshuttle -> I guess the purpose of the tool was to route/forward all incoming traffic from `myserver` to `TARGET`

Comment: Ad ssh port forwarding: This has nothing to do with sshuttle. I agree the question is asked in a confusing way (2 in 1), sorry for that. I am learning about networking and the topic of forwarding and traffic routing has been bugging me. What I meant was more like a curiosity rather than practical thing. I was not sure that if I forward -p 22 from `myserver` to `TARGET`, then when I run`ssh myserver` I am essentially connecting to `TARGET`. So how could I ssh to `myserver` if all traffic is sent staright to `TARGET`

Comment: The `sshuttle` is for situations where you need VPN without installing VPN. It puts all your traffic into the SSH connection, protecting you from the possibly hostile local environment and making you appear as your server to the outside world. So you got its purpose wrong.